# Adding a score module with images

Tags: lua, coronasdk

If i use the first ideal, i'll have something like that :

```
mydata.score = mydata.score + 5
        scoreText.text = mydata.score
    if mydata.score == 5 then
                score_5.isVisible=true
                score_5.x=score_title.x+score_title.width+135
            end
            if mydata.score == 10 then
                score_5.isVisible=false
                score_1.isVisible=true
                score_1.x=score_title.x+score_title.width+108
                score_0.isVisible=true
                score_0.x=score_title.x+score_title.width+135
            end
            if mydata.score == 15 then
                score_5.isVisible=false
                score_1.isVisible=true
                score_1.x=score_title.x+score_title.width+108
                score_0.isVisible=true
                score_0.x=score_title.x+score_title.width+135
            end
```

Is it possible to have a function which can "generalize" the process ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use images without bothering with spritesheet...
You would have to handle it by having 5 images always displayed, and using removeSelf / newImageRect everytime a digit is updated. The screen might flicker though, in that case.

Using an imagesheet would be more setup: in that case you would have 5 sprites, each sprite knowing a sequence to display each possible digit from 0 to 9, and would need to ask each sprite to run the correct sequence according to the number displayed.